# Create dictionary based on matrix data frame index and a second data frame value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matrix

I have the following CSV data frame `df` imported using pandas `df= pd.read_csv("Example.csv", header=0, index_col="Forest")` (the numeric values are distances)

```
Forest,Bell Bay,Surrey Hills,Smithton,Hobart
Coupe 1,158,194,10,49
Coupe 2,156,169,71,84
Coupe 3,10,186,101,163
Coupe 4,47,94,134,139
Coupe 5,144,61,135,56
Coupe 6,27,27,134,36
Coupe 7,114,4,143,113
Coupe 8,71,170,190,140
Coupe 9,94,54,73,128
Coupe 10,46,194,92,36
```

I have a second data frame imported `df2` using `df2 = pd.read_csv("ExampleSupply.csv", header=0, index_col="Forest")` (the numeric values are supply quantities)

```
Forest,Supply
Coupe 1,600
Coupe 2,100
Coupe 3,900
Coupe 4,300
Coupe 5,300
Coupe 6,400
Coupe 7,900
Coupe 8,700
Coupe 9,500
Coupe 10,300
```

The column `Forest` is matching between the two data frames.
I created a list of forests `I` from `df` using:

```
I = df.index.tolist()
```

Result:

```
['Coupe 1', 'Coupe 2', 'Coupe 3', 'Coupe 4', 'Coupe 5', 'Coupe 6', 'Coupe 7', 'Coupe 8', 'Coupe 9', 'Coupe 10']
```

And a list of destinations `J` in `df` using:

```
J = df.columns.values.tolist()
```

Result:

```
['Bell Bay', 'Surrey Hills', 'Smithton', 'Hobart']
```

The list of tuples (arcs) was created using:

```
arcs = [(i, j) for i in I for j in J]
```

Result:

```
[('Coupe 1', 'Bell Bay'), ('Coupe 1', 'Surrey Hills'), ('Coupe 1', 'Smithton'), ('Coupe 1', 'Hobart'), ('Coupe 2', 'Bell Bay'), ('Coupe 2', 'Surrey Hills'), ('Coupe 2', 'Smithton'), ('Coupe 2', 'Hobart'), ('Coupe 3', 'Bell Bay'), ('Coupe 3', 'Surrey Hills'), ('Coupe 3', 'Smithton'), ('Coupe 3', 'Hobart'), ('Coupe 4', 'Bell Bay'), ('Coupe 4', 'Surrey Hills'), ('Coupe 4', 'Smithton'), ('Coupe 4', 'Hobart'), ('Coupe 5', 'Bell Bay'), ('Coupe 5', 'Surrey Hills'), ('Coupe 5', 'Smithton'), ('Coupe 5', 'Hobart'), ('Coupe 6', 'Bell Bay'), ('Coupe 6', 'Surrey Hills'), ('Coupe 6', 'Smithton'), ('Coupe 6', 'Hobart'), ('Coupe 7', 'Bell Bay'), ('Coupe 7', 'Surrey Hills'), ('Coupe 7', 'Smithton'), ('Coupe 7', 'Hobart'), ('Coupe 8', 'Bell Bay'), ('Coupe 8', 'Surrey Hills'), ('Coupe 8', 'Smithton'), ('Coupe 8', 'Hobart'), ('Coupe 9', 'Bell Bay'), ('Coupe 9', 'Surrey Hills'), ('Coupe 9', 'Smithton'), ('Coupe 9', 'Hobart'), ('Coupe 10', 'Bell Bay'), ('Coupe 10', 'Surrey Hills'), ('Coupe 10', 'Smithton'), ('Coupe 10', 'Hobart')]
```

I want to create a dictionary of the `row index` in `df` (that refers to the `Forest` in `I`) and quantity values in `df2`. The dictionary should look like this:

```
dQ = {'Coupe 1': 600, 'Coupe 2': 100, 'Coupe 3': 900, 'Coupe 4': 300, 'Coupe 5': 300, 'Coupe 6': 400, 'Coupe 7': 900, 'Coupe 8': 700, 'Coupe 9': 500, 'Coupe 10': 300}
```

The quantity values `Supply` in `df2` should be linked with the `Forest` in `df`by referring to the list `I` or the key in `arcs`.

Can anyone suggest the best way to formulate this dictionary? This is only a small set of I(10) and J(4) in a combined matrix. My methods have to be applicable to very large datasets with over 10 million I*J combinations. Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop through the list `I` and find the corresponding row in `df2` and pick the `df2['Supply']` and add it to the desired dict.

```
dQ = {}
for forest in I:
    dQ[forest] = df2.loc[forest]['Supply']
print(dQ)
```

Result:

```
{'Coupe 1': 600, 'Coupe 2': 100, 'Coupe 3': 900, 'Coupe 4': 300, 'Coupe 5': 300, 'Coupe 6': 400, 'Coupe 7': 900, 'Coupe 8': 700, 'Coupe 9': 500, 'Coupe 10': 300}
```

Pythonic way -

```
dQ = {forest: df2.loc[forest]['Supply'] for forest in I}
```

Question - Why do you need to lookup 'Forest' from `df` as your `df2` already has the same index and the 'Forest' values matches. If you can just use df2 data and do the same - convert the `df2` to a dict using

```
df2.to_dict()['Supply']
```

It should also give you the same result

Comment: Thanks for your help. This worked.
Not sure, pretty new to it. The two data frames are independent and I wanna make sure that the information in ```df2``` is connected with the information in ```df``` by checking the ```Forest``` name. In my set of constraints, I use the ```supply``` and ```distance``` values and wanna be sure they are connected to the same ```forest```.